# Mercurial : Tag a particular changeset

Tags: mercurial, tags, changeset

I want to write an application which identifies the current changesets and tags them.
I do know we can get the changeset by using  `hg identify`.

Once I get the changeset, is there a way I can tag it?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#tag):

```
hg tag [-f] [-l] [-m TEXT] [-d DATE] [-u USER] [-r REV] NAME...
```

So this should work:

```
$ hg tag -r revision tagname
```

Comment: Thanks for the document. It helps a lot

Comment: Also `hg help tag`. Lots of useful help built-in.

Comment: Hmm, when I do this, it creates a new branch with the changeset of my tag-change on it. Is there a way to get it to put that changeset on the current branch? Edit: Nevermind, I was upped to the changeset also; once I ran "hg up" to get to tip, the command worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ hg tag -r changeset tagname
```

Thanks